If $g(x)=\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}x$ and $\frac{g(x)}{(x-y)(x-z)}+\frac{g(y)}{(y-z)(y-x)}+\frac{g(z)}{(z-x)(z-y)}=\frac k{xyz}$, find $k$

If $g(x)=\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}x$ and $\frac{g(x)}{(x-y)(x-z)}+\frac{g(y)}{(y-z)(y-x)}+\frac{g(z)}{(z-x)(z-y)}=\frac k{xyz}$, find $k$

My Attempt:
$\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{x(x-y)(x-z)}+\frac{(y-a)(y-b)}{y(y-z)(y-x)}+\frac{(z-a)(z-b)}{z(z-x)(z-y)}=\frac k{xyz}$
$\frac1{(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}\left(-\frac{(x-a)(x-b)(y-z)}{x}-\frac{(y-a)(y-b)(z-x)}{y}-\frac{(z-a)(z-b)(x-y)}{z}\right)=\frac k{xyz}$

The quickest solution, in my opinion, is to assume $x=y=z=1$ and then alternate through some choices of $a$ and $b$. There is probably some algebraic method, but in a contest, you are better off atleast finding the answer, usually the answer helps you reverse engineer the solution

@Kraken wouldn't that make denominator zero?

@Kraken taking $x=a, y=b, z=c$ gives $k=0$

Ah right, well then assume something else. $k$ is a constant. And 0 means something. Let me think, I'll revert to you. Usually setting them all equal works, but I didn't notice the denominator becomes 0. Good idea to substitute $x=a, y=b, z=c$ tho!

substituting what you tried actually gives you $k=ab$

In which contest  this question was asked?

@RicciTen JEE mock exam.

In jee you can in many cases use tricks like mentioned in comments

@RicciTen yes, I agree.

Cool question
We want to find
$$S=g(x)(z-y)+g(y)(x-z)+g(z)(y-x)$$ because dividing this by $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ gives us your $LHS$.
By simply substituting their corresponding values according to the functions definition,(a bit tedious)
$$S=\frac{ab(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}{xyz}\\\implies \frac{S}{(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}=\frac{ab}{xyz}$$
Thus $k=ab$

Nice idea, but I think OP was trying to avoid doing the algebra. Maybe there's some other solution.

I think the question was made on the foundation of this property only...still I'll check. It's impossible to evade algebra completely @Kraken

Yeah, it seems, good solution tho. +1!
